# Difference between format and internalformat

Tags: opengl

I did search and read stuff about this but couldn't understand it.

**What's the difference between a texture internal format and format in a call like**

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

**?**

Let's assume that `data` is an array of 32 x 32 pixel values where there are four bytes per each pixel (unsigned char data 0-255) for red, green, blue and alpha.

What's the difference between the first `GL_RGBA` and the second one? Why is `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` invalid in this context?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The *format* (7th argument), together with the *type* argument, describes the *data* you pass in as the last argument. So the *format*/*type* combination defines the memory layout of the *data* you pass in.

*internalFormat* (2nd argument) defines the format that OpenGL should use to store the data internally.

Often times, the two will be very similar. And in fact, it is beneficial to make the two formats directly compatible. Otherwise there will be a conversion while loading the data, which can hurt performance. Full OpenGL allows combinations that require conversions, while OpenGL ES limits the supported combinations so that conversions are not needed in most cases.

The reason `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` is not legal in this case that there are rules about which conversions between *format* and *internalFormat* are supported. In this case, `GL_RGBA` for the *internalFormat* specifies a normalized format, while `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` for *format* specifies that the input consists of values that should be used as integers. There is no conversion defined between these two.

While `GL_RGBA` for *internalFormat* is still supported for backwards compatibility, sized types are generally used for *internalFormat* in modern versions of OpenGL. For example, if you want to store the data as an 8-bit per component RGBA image, the value for *internalFormat* is `GL_RGBA8`.

Frankly, I think there would be cleaner ways of defining these APIs. But this is just the way it works. Partly it evolved this way to maintain backwards compatibility to OpenGL versions where features were much more limited. Newer versions of OpenGL add the `glTexStorage*()` entry points, which make some of this nicer because it separates the internal data allocation and the specification of the data.

Comment: The same stands: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497195/difference-between-format-and-internalformat#comment56736641_34497470) is my last clarification on this

Answer (score 23):

The *internal* format describes how the texture shall be stored in the GPU. The *format* describes how the format of your pixel data in client memory (together with the *type* parameter).

Note that the internal format does specify both the number of channels (1 to 4) as well as the data type, while for the pixel data in client memory, both are specified via two separate parameters.

The GL will convert your pixel data to the internal format. If you want efficient texture uploads, you should use matching formats so that there is no conversion needed. But be aware that most GPUs store the texture data in `BGRA` order, this still is represented by the internal format `GL_RBGA` - the internal format only describes the number of channels and the data type, the internal layout is totally GPU-specific. However, that means that it is often recommended for maximum performance to use `GL_BGRA` as the *format* of your pixel data in client memory.

> Let's assume that data is an array of 32 x 32 pixel values where there
>   are four bytes per each pixel (unsigned char data 0-255) for red,
>   green, blue and alpha.
>   What's the difference between the first GL_RGBA and the second one?

The first, *internalFormat* tells the GL that it should store the texture as 4 channel (RGBA) with normalized integer in the preferred precision (8 bit per channel). The second one, *format* tells the Gl that you are providing 4 channels per pixel in the R,G,B,A order.

You could for example supply the data as 3-channel RGB data and the GL would automatically extend this to RGBA (with setting A to 1) if the internal format is left at RGBA. You also could supply only the Red channel.

The other way around, if you use `GL_RED` as *internalFormat*, the GL would ignore the GB and A channel in your input data.

Also note that the data types will be converted. If you provide a pixel RGB with 32 bit float per channel, you could use `GL_FLOAT`. However, when you still use the `GL_RGBA` internal format, the GL will *convert* these to normalized integers with 8 bpit per channel, so the extra precision is lost. If you want the GL to use the floating point precision, you would also have to use a floating point texture format like `GL_RGBA32F`.

> Why is GL_RGBA_INTEGER invalid in this context?

the `_INTEGER` formats are for unnormalized integer textures. There is no automatic conversion for integer textures in the GL. You have to use an integer internal format, *AND* you have to specify your pixel data with some `_INTEGER` format, otherwise it will result in an error.

Comment: Got it, one additional question: is `GL_RGBA` as internal format stored signed or unsigned? I.e. should I access it with a sampler2D or usampler2D? And `rgba8ui` attribute for a compute shader?

Comment: GL_RGBA is a _normalized_ _unsigned_ integer format. THe normalized means that you will acces the results as _floating point_ in the range [0,1] ([-1,1] for signed formats) using the standard `sampler` types. For `usampler` and `isampler` types, you **must** use unnormalized integer formats.