# How can I store positive and negative values in a texture?

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm creating a program where I'm using the GPU to do computations (via fragment shaders) and need to store signed values inside textures.

My texture is initialized with GL_FLOAT, like so:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
```

And from what I understand about opengl, individual texels must be in the range [0,1] when GL_FLOAT is used (when I experimented with glClear, my values would be clipped to this range). So what I've been doing so far is scaling my values down to the range [-1,1] based on their actual range, then converting that to [0,1] before writing it back to the texture. The next shader that needs to work with the data reads the texel value and moves it to [-1,1] before continuing and so on...

My question is, is this the right way to deal with negative values? I'm pretty sure the repeated conversions are causing fp errors to accumulate which obviously isn't good for accuracy.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also: [Difference between format and internalformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497195/difference-between-format-and-internalformat)

The *internal format* (third parameter of `glTexImage2D`) decides how the GPU stores and interprets those values, not the *type* parameter of `glTexImage2D` (second-to-last parameter). That parameter decides how the driver should interpret your client/host-side memory when uploading to the texture, which you currently don't use by using `nullptr`.

You could use the signed 8-bit `GL_RGBA8_SNORM` or the 16-bit floating point `GL_RGBA16F` or 32-bit floating-point `GL_RGBA32F` sized *internal format* for the texture.

Generally, you should always use a *sized* internal format to be explicit about what you want and get.

See the table on: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

So, if you only need 8-bit resolution, and values in the range [-1, 1], then you can use:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8_SNORM, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
```

The second-to-last argument is actually irrelevant, because we are not uploading any texel data to the texture.

Comment: So are the SNORM internal formats the only ones that can store negative values? (i.e. reading the texel inside a shader returns negative value). But from reading the docs it sounds like those formats are only compatible with integer types which isn't as convenient for the sort of operations that I need to do.

Comment: I poked around with the api and it seems like there's something fundamental here I'm not understanding. I created a texture using GL_RGB+GL_RGB16_SNORM+GL_SHORT, then used glClear to fill it with -0.5f, then read it back using glGetTexImage. The odd thing when calling glGetTexImage with GL_RGB,GL_SHORT and reading into a short buffer, I get incorrect values (zeros) but when using GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT and reading into a float buffer I get the correct -0.5. I would've expected the short buffer to work because I used 16bit values as the internal format and type.

Comment: Did some more reading and found this little blurb:

"Both normalized integer and floating-point formats will resolve, in the shader, to a vector of floating-point values"
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format

Rather unintuitive and makes me wonder what the difference is ultimately between a format such as GL_RG16F compared to GL_RG16.